# Typescript bundling and references for IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

I'm currently trying to develop using IntelliJ and my issue is that for each typescript file I have to add an explicit reference to everything used in that file.

Also, the transpiled output of TS->JS also needs to be referenced individually.

Is there a way to lessen the friction here?
It would be nice to not have to deal with references between files.
And some sort of bundling for the TS files would also be nice.

Comment: I am using WebStorm (which should be basically the same implementation of TypeScript editor) and references between files are not needed - at least I have no issues with it. Maybe you could try to add [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) to your project.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you can avoid references, but I am using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) and it make code looks like java/c#, intellisense working fine

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <!-- 
You can add only this line, all other js files require js will add automatically at runtime. 
data-main is an entry point -> app.js in this case 
-->
    <script src="require.js" data-main="app"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

app.ts

```
import module1 = require("module1");
import module2 = require("module2");
var class1 = new module1.Class1();
var class2 = new module2.Class2();
```

module1.ts

```
export class Class1{

    constructor() {
        console.log("Class1 created")
    }
}
```

module2.ts

```
export class Class2{
    constructor() {
        console.log("Class2 created")
    }
}
```

Of course you must add require.js in to the project and add "--module amd" in Idea Settings->Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript -> Command line options
[image]
This way is more readable and you can see in where you use external code and you can cleanup unused imports and another benefit you can write modular code.